# Solving double infinite sets of equations - Plate buckling with all sides clamped - LEVY (1942)

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve a double infinite sets of equations which is shown in the attached picture:
[Equation Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljk4t.png).

It is a solution to a rectangular plate buckling with all sides built-in. The goal is to solve for K, which is the buckling coefficient.

The equation was originally derived by Levy in his 1942 paper: "BUCKLING OF RECTANGULAR PLATES WITH BUILT-IN EDGES", S. LEVY, JOURNAL OF APPLIED MECHANICS, VOL. 9, PG. 171, 1942.

Levy says, to solve the equation, the determinant of the coefficients of km and tn must be zero.
However, I can't figure out how to write out the equations to set up the matrix of coefficients where I can start calculating its determinant.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize what I have tried so far:

Attempting to solve for $\phi = 1,$ and with $t_{1}$ and $k_1$ to $k_7$ determinants as a 1st trial like Levy did in Table 2 of his paper, the $K$ solution should be $10.047.$

These determinants means that $n = 1 $and $m = 1, 3, 5 $and $7.$ Levy did not consider even $m $ variables. Anyway, there should be $5$ equations since there are $5$ variables. The first equation should give $1$ equation and the second equation should give $4 $ equations.

Now, expanding the infinite series (I hope I am doing this part correctly):
Equation $1$ $(m = 1$ to $7, n = 1):$

$\frac{(k_1 + t_1)}{(1-K)} + \frac{(3k_3 + 9t1)}{(100-9K)} + \frac{(5k5 + 25t1)}{(676-25K)} + \frac{(7k7 + 49t1)}{(2500-49K)} = 0$

Reordering:
$(1/(4-K))*k1 + (3/(100-9K))*k3 + (5/(676-25K))*k5 + (7/(2500-49K))*k7 + ( 1/(4-K) + 9/(100-9K) + 25/(676-25K) + 49/(2500-49K) )*t1 = 0$

$Equation$ $2$ $(m = 1, n = 1):$
$(k_1 + t_1)/(4-K) = 0$
$Reordering:
(1/(4-K))*k_1 + (1/(4-K))*t_1 = 0$

$Equation$ $2$ $(m = 3, n = 1):$
$(k_3 + 3*t_1)/(100-9K) = 0$
$Reordering:
(1/(100-9K))*k_3 + (3/(100-9K))*t_1 = 0$

$Equation$ $2$ $(m = 5, n = 1):
(k_5 + 5*t_1)/(676-25K) = 0$
$Reordering:
(1/(676-25K))*k_5 + (5/(676-25K))*t_1 = 0$

$Equation$ $2$ $(m = 7, n = 1):
(k_7 + 7*t_1)/(2500-49K) = 0$
$Reordering:
(1/(2500-49K))*k_7 + (7/(2500-49K))*t_1 = 0$

Is this approach correct? Because I can't seem to get logical values for $K$ when I put the coefficients into a matrix and iterate $K $ to get a zero determinant.

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2038404)

Comment: It is not an additional information. It is an answer (my own) to the problem. But I need to know if my own answer is correct (I believe it is not). Hence, the reason for a separate post so others can vote it up or down depending on its accuracy.